# Using Awk to print desired lines of nslookup

Tags: awk, nslookup

I'm looking to print the name and IP that results from an nslookup so I can output them to a file.

When I run an `nslookup` on a host, I get a result like this:

```
Server: 10.10.10.10
Address: 10.10.10.10#53

Name: EXAMPLE.example.com
Address: 10.10.10.100
```

I want to output the name and IP into separate columns of a file, so my command right now, is this:

```
nslookup EXAMPLE.example.com | awk 'FNR ==4 {print$2}' | awk 'FNR ==5 {print$2}'
```

I'm getting nothing even though the separate awk's return the right value on their own. I realize why this won't work, but I'm wondering the right syntax for printing out both of these results into their respective columns.

Comment: can you please post an example of desired output

Comment: Will there always be exactly one `A` record returned?

Comment: The problem seem to be  the second AWK is getting as input the sole word (field) parsed by the first awk, hence the output is empty as you don't have a second field on it

Comment: ... the second awk is only getting a single *record* (`FNR==4`) - so `FNR==5` will never be true

Answer (score 1):

```
nslookup EXAMPLE.example.com \
| awk '/^Name:/ {N=$2}; /^Address:/ {A=$2}; END {print N,A}'
```

Will print only the last name and address, but if you want them all:

```
nslookup EXAMPLE.example.com \
| awk '/^Name:/ {N=$2}; /^Address:/ {print N,$2}'
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to mach properly:
nslookup www.americanas.com.br
Server:         201.21.192.119
Address:        201.21.192.119#53
Non-authoritative answer:
www.americanas.com.br   .
Name:   e6654.dscg.akamaiedge.net
Address: 2.23.99.232
Name:   e6654.dscg.akamaiedge.net
Address: 2600:1419:a000:182::19fe
Name:   e6654.dscg.akamaiedge.net
Address: 2600:1419:a000:18e::19fe

nslookup www.americanas.com.br | awk '/^Name:/ {N=$1}; /^Address:/ {A=$2}; END {print N,A}'
Name: 2600:1419:a000:182::19fe

Comment: Perhaps you should execute the command I gave you, iso. some variation.

Comment: @gerard-h-pille what do you mean?

Comment: You executed another command than the one in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dig` instead:

```
$ dig +noall +answer example.com | awk '{ print $1, $NF }'
example.com. 93.184.216.34

$ dig +noall +answer www.google.com | awk '{ print $1, $NF }'
www.google.com. 172.217.20.36
```

The `awk` script prints the first and last whitespace-delimited fields from the output of the `dig` command (the raw output also contains a few other columns in-between these).

---

Your command:

```
nslookup EXAMPLE.example.com | awk 'FNR ==4 {print$2}' | awk 'FNR ==5 {print$2}'
```

This does not work since the second `awk` program is trying to get the fifth line from the output of the first `awk` program, which only outputs one single line.

Something like this might have worked,

```
$ nslookup example.com | awk 'FNR == 4 || FNR == 5 { print $2 }'
answer:
example.com
```

but on my system, as you can see, the wanted data is on other lines (not line 4 and 5). This may work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
nslookup -type=A cdnjs.cloudflare.com | awk '/^Name:/ {c=2;N=$2} !--c {print N,$2}'
```

which will print all records:

```
cdnjs.cloudflare.com 104.16.18.94
cdnjs.cloudflare.com 104.16.19.94
```

Unlike other solutions, this script will only match the actual answer and not the DNS server address. It won't output anything in the case of failure.

This was inspired by [an answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105).